# Caching dynamically-generated images in front-end

Tags: javascript, caching, ember.js

I am currently working with the following situation: I have an Ember front-end with N entities, and the user can view dynamically-generated chart images for each of these entities.
For this purpose, when the user wants to view the chart for on an entity, the following happens:

1. the front-end sends a request for generating a chart image to a back-end endpoint
2. this image is then passed to the front-end in the endpoint's response, as a base64 encoded image
3. the front-end displays this image
4. now, the user can select a new entity, etc.

At the moment, the user has to wait for a chart image to be loaded 3-5 seconds, no matter whether this entity's chart has been viewed before.
This is quite annoying: wait to view chart for entity A, then wait to view chart for entity B, then wait again if you want to see entity A again, etc.

I want to cache somehow the already viewed images in the front-end, in order to avoid this waiting time. (The content of the images does not change frequently, perhaps once a day or so, so this is not a problem).

Can this be done with Ember, or am I looking at this from a wrong point of view and an entirely different strategy is required?

Comment: Do you use ember-data?

Comment: This is an old addon, but you may want to look at how [ember-img-manager](https://github.com/huafu/ember-img-manager) does this.

Comment: @Lux Thanks guys -- we ended up using sessionStorage to store the base64 strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.peekRecord()` first and check if it has any result. If it's on the ember store, it will show to you. You can visualize if you are caching correctly on Ember inspector.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid my post was not clear -- the images are NOT part of the store. I was curious if Ember had any "on the fly" caching mechanisms that did not involve using the store. Anyway, we ended up using session storage.